# Clicking on each item of listview in a fragment is not working

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a listview and want to set an onClickListener on each item in this fragment but it's not working.I also wanted to set a contextMenu on the listview and that's not working either.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    purchasedItemsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchased_items_fragment , container, false);

    db = new StoreDataBase(getActivity() , Consts.StoreDB.DB_NAME , Consts.StoreDB.DB_VERSION);
    storeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    listView = (ListView) purchasedItemsView.findViewById(R.id.storeListView);
    adapter  = new StoreListViewAdapter(getContext() , R.layout.store_item_row , storeArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter .notifyDataSetChanged();

    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    sendData(purchasedItemsView);

    return purchasedItemsView;
}


 private void sendData(View view){

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        final String[] names = bundle.getStringArray(Constc.Data.names);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.storeListView);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Data" , "clicked");
            }
        });
    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** reinitialize `listview` after you have done it once in `onCreateView()`. Therefore, **remove** this line from `sendData()` method:

```
// remove this
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.storeListView);
```

Then you need to move this part of code outside of `if` statement or inside of `onCreateView()` method.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Log.e("Data" , "clicked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Point 1:
Seems your array list is empty, so fill some data

```
storeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//-------------------------------------
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    final String[] names = bundle.getStringArray(Constc.Data.names);
    if(names != null && names.length() > 0) {
        storeArrayList.addAll(names);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------
listView = (ListView) purchasedItemsView.findViewById(R.id.storeListView);
adapter  = new StoreListViewAdapter(getContext() , R.layout.store_item_row , storeArrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Point 2: You don't need "notifyDataSetChanged();" right after you set the adapter.

```
//adapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Point 3:
Use long click listener for showing context menu

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Log.e("Data" , "long press clicked");
         //show dialog or context menu dialog.
    }
});
```

Point 4:
comment the sendData method and use the onclick directly

```
//sendData(purchasedItemsView);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Log.e("Data" , "clicked");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. 
Vote Up - If you like it.